# SQL Server LIKE operator with NCHAR column comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, string-comparison

I have the following piece of code. I don't quite understand only the first `EXEC` statement has result. Can anyone help to explain please?

```
USE tempdb;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.students') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.students;
CREATE TABLE dbo.students
(
    id   INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name NCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.students(name)
SELECT c FROM(VALUES(N'ab'), (N'cd'), (N'ef'), (N'gh')) AS DATA(c);

SELECT *, DATALENGTH(name)FROM dbo.students;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.check_address') IS NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.check_address AS SELECT ''to be replaced''');
END;
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.check_address @name NCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.students WHERE name LIKE N'%' + @name + N'%';
END;
GO

EXEC check_address N'ab';
EXEC check_address N'a';
```

Comment: @DavidG there are two ... one `N'ab'`, one `N'a'`

Comment: My first thought would be to try with `nvarchar(10)` instead of `nchar(10)` for both the column and the parameter

Comment: @MarcGravell I really shouldn't Stack Overflow so late at night!

Comment: This code is not from production, it's just testing code and I'm trying to understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`N'ab'`, as a **fixed width** type like `nchar(10)`, is actually `N'ab        '`. Thus it matches `LIKE N'%ab        %'`, but does not match `LIKE N'%a         %'`.

Use `nvarchar(10)` instead of `nchar(10)` for both the column and the parameter, and it should work like you expect.

Comment: But the second exec statement in my example code is '%a%', not '%a %', right?

Comment: @Ogrish nope. The parameter is `nchar(10)`. The input data is expanded to that **before** the concatenation with `%` happens

Comment: Oh D'oh! I finally understood it. Thank you very much Marc!